# How to Add Post Thumbnail Image only on Home, Archive in Underscore Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically, I want to add thumbnail image on home page only, but it shows thumbnail image (Featured image) on single content also, which i don't want to load in single page.

I Want to add thumbnail like this:

[image: example]

( from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b2IazPBlw5peVQz1RZh-PaO3y7GLmRwJ/view?usp=sharing) )

Theme: Underscore development theme

My content.php:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package DevWP
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
            ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php devwp_posted_on(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php devwp_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php

        if ( is_single() ) {
        the_content( sprintf(
            wp_kses(
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'devwp' ),
                array(
                    'span' => array(
                        'class' => array(),
                    ),
                )
            ),
            get_the_title()
        ) );
        } else {
            the_excerpt();
        }

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'devwp' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php devwp_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
<hr>
```

Comment: Not clear, where the above code is rendered, is this from the home page or from the article (?) page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what your goal is, but if you want to show the featured image only on homepage and not for the rest of your pages, than you can try 2 things. 1st inside the content.php file to check if you're on the homepage with [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) :

```
if(is_front_page()){
  devwp_post_thumbnail();// I suppose this is echoing your thumbnail
}
```

The second thing you may do is to create a custom page template for your pages where you're not going to output the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Put This Code...

```
if( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  devwp_post_thumbnail();
}
```